# multiple google maps markers with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've had a look around SO and found some situations similar to mine but haven't found a solution.
I'm learning PHP, Javascript as I go along so the code may be a little off but here goes:

I have a Google map with a postcode search function working - The postcode and Lat/Long are stored in a Mysql DB.  What I need now is a function to place any amount of markers on the map for specific postcodes - in time I hope to expand the function to allow something like postcode+10 miles, etc depending on the zoom level.  The code below will bring back the lat/long for the markers but it sticks a "," at the end of each results and therefore when I pass it into the javascript, it's an invalid parameter - please be sure that I know that the way I'm doing all of this is in-efficient - I'm learning as I go along :)

**PHP function:**

```
// get markers Function
if(!function_exists("getMarkers"))
{

//Get Markers Function
function getMarkers() 
    {
//prep the query
include ('../../secure/db_conn.php');

$currentPcode = searchPostcode($_POST['postcode']);

$tsearch = $con->prepare("SELECT t.CompanyName, p.lat, p.lng FROM Traders t, cpo_data p WHERE t.Postcode LIKE p.Postcode");
$tsearch->bindParam(1,$currentPcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$tsearch->execute();
$tresults = $tsearch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($tresults as $row) 
 {

$Company = $row['CompanyName'];
$Tlat = (string)$row['p.lat'];
$Tlng = (string)$row['p.lng'];

 }
echo $Tlat .", " .$Tlng;
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

//postcode function call
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo searchPostcode($_POST['postcode']); ?>);

//markers function call
var locations=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo getMarkers(); ?>);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var mymap=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

// To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
    { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]),
    map: mymap
   });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i]);
      infowindow.open(mymap, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
    }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated - my current knowledge is only PHP and Javascript (and as mentioned previously, it's beginners knowledge).

Forgot to add, When I use google developer tools in Chrome to analyse the page, I can see the following which confirms it is picking up the lat/long, but with a comma at the end (I think it's to do with it being an array but not sure how I deal with it):

`var locations=new google.maps.LatLng(53.51139969260000, -2.54091408438000, );`

Comment: Not sure if this is a crude way of doing it but I did the following in the PHP echo: echo trim($Tlat .", " .$Tlng, ', ');  This removed the comma and my map shows - however, my markers aren't appearing and there's no error ... I'm thinking my javascript loop may be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place the markers fetched from the database you have two problems:

**PHP Code**

You echo only the last pair of lat/lng fetched:

```
foreach ($tresults as $row) 
 {

   $Company = $row['CompanyName'];
   $Tlat = (string)$row['p.lat'];
   $Tlng = (string)$row['p.lng'];

 }
echo $Tlat .", " .$Tlng;
```

A solution would be:

```
$locations = array();
foreach ($tresults as $row) 
{

  $Company = $row['CompanyName'];
  $Tlat = (string)$row['p.lat'];
  $Tlng = (string)$row['p.lng'];

  $locations[] = "[" . $Tlat .", " .$Tlng . "]";
}
echo srpintf("[%s]", implode(", ", $locations);
```

Then in your javascript code you store an array of coordinates in `locations`.

**Javascript code**

Now in your javascript code:

```
var locations = <?php getMarkers(); ?>
```

You have now in locations the array like this:

```
[[53.51139969260000, -2.54091408438000], [...], ...]
```

Then in the loop you should access to coordinates as an array:

```
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
    { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
    map: mymap
   });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + ", " + locations[i][1]);
      infowindow.open(mymap, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Pedro, I've re-worked my code as you suggested.  The function will work, however the output looks like this:                 53.60081497210000, -2.27129547711000[[, ], [, ], [, ], [, ], [, ]]  If I limit my SQL results to only show the one lat/lng, the results appear like this:          53.60081497210000, -2.27129547711000[]

Comment: It seems like `getMarkers()` first echoes the last result coordinates and later echoes the `$locations` array. Can you check if there are two `echo`? And, in `$locations[]` assignment, can you check if the two variables `$Tlng` `$Tlat` have data?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply Pedro - wife's going through Chemo which is taking a toll on time.

Comment: I've re-worked my SQL script to bring back 5 mile radius based on my lat/long - and it works when tested.  The $locations array now looks like this in a test example: [[53.60081497210000, -2.27129547711000], [53.60081497210000, -2.27129547711000],[53.59287004000000, -2.28641317514000]] .  So from that, it looks as if we need to just trim off the [] which are being passed and then iterate through them in Java?  Please correct me if I'm wrong. again apologies for the late response.

Comment: got it - your code was dead on in the end, I just had to play around with some schoolboy mistakes that I missed in the developer console - elusive } symbols floating around and forgetting to rename my map back from mymap to map ... either way, the code works perfectly now :-) really appreciate your time and patience with this Pedro - thanks again